# Headphone "locks" sound

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, thinkpad, headphones

I have a Thinkpad X1 running Ubuntu 22.04 and a "ThinkPad Hybrid USB-C with USB-A Dock". If I insert a headphone into the jack, the sound will only come out of the headphones... I can't select the speakers on the monitor. My last Thinkpad (running RHEL 8 or 9) and docking station did allow me to leave the headphones in and still switch the sound around.

How can I fix this in Ubuntu?

Comment: You can open sound settings in system settings and change the default device